# PHP and iOS App to modify XML

Tags: php, ios, xml

The setup for my app is essentially simple.  There is an XML file stored online filled with 'requests'  from users, that my app parses into a UITableView.  There are two options for the user, they can simply view the items from the XML and details on them, or they can submit a 'request' which will be added to the XML for others to view.

In my app, I have set up the basic XML already, with just a couple of dummy entries, just for testing purposes.  Everything parses fine.

My main question on this is if there is something either in Obj-C that I can use, or if I need to set up a PHP script to do this.  I want to be able to have the user fill out all the UITextFields for Name, Date, Email, Request, and once they click submit, it take all that information, and add a new item to the XML stored online, with a tag for each of the UITextFields they filled out in that new item.

I've looked at http://www.xmlobjective.com/create-an-xml-document-using-php/ and I think it may be in the direction I am looking at going, I guess I just need some help and direction with setting up the script and getting the app to communicate with it.

Comment: When you use JSON you can use iOS system provided NSJSONSerialization class. Otherwise, writing out your own XML should be trivial.

Comment: @Joride So would your suggestion be that I store a JSON file online and use iOS to add to it?  Also, you say writing out XML should be trivial.  Care to elaborate any, please?

Comment: If you have the freedom to use any format, I would go for JSON. Most web-frameworks can handle this very well, and iOS now also does conversion from JSON to NSDictionary / NSData. Writing out a small number of fields into xml can be done manually: XML has a fairly simple spec, that is what I meant.

Comment: Thank you @Joride.  I haven't done much before with appending anything in JSON or XML before.  What steps do I need to take, or are there any tutorials for editing a JSON file on a web-server from an iOS app?

Comment: On the app side, there is NSJSONSerialization. It will convert between JSON and NSDictionary. Use the mutable options to append to an already existing dictionary. On the server side: basically, you need to have a place to upload the new JSON-file to (maybe your own server), or you need to have server which can perform some logic, maybe in PHP, PERL or Python. I guess there are either built-in-the-language solutions or maybe examples on github for these languages on how to handle and store JSON efficiently.